# using fscanf to read a file puts a 0@ in first line

Tags: c, file

So I am using a while loop to read from a file. My class assignment to to build an assembler. So we basically have to ignore lines that are blank or are comments (in this format ;Comment). I have everything working properly except for one thing, if the file starts with a blank line for some reason the program just ceases to work. To try and troubleshoot the problem I printed out each line that the program read before I interpreted it. For any other blank line it simply puts a blank line, however for the first line it prints a 0@. Initially I thought maybe this was just something that happened to be in the memory when the program ran but then it was 0@ every time and I thought this had to be more than a coincidence. Anyways, any help with what may be wrong would be helpful. Thanks!

```
int findOrigin(FILE *infile)
{
    char line[LINE_SIZE]; 
    char origin[LINE_SIZE];
    int nonComments = 0;
    int hexOrigin = 0;

    int lineCount = 0; 

    int done = 0;

    char c;

    while (fscanf(infile, "%[^\n]s", line) != EOF && lineCount < LIMIT && !done)
    {
        lineCount++;

        fscanf(infile, "%c", &c);  //Get rid of extra newline.

        removeSpaces(line);
        toUpperCase(line);
        if (line[0] != 0 && line[0] != ';')
        {
            done = 1;
            if (!strncmp(line, ".ORIG", 5))
            {
                nonComments++;
            }
            if (nonComments > 1)
            {
                printf("ERROR 1: Missing origin directive. Origin must be first line in program.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (line[5] == 'X')
                {
                    sscanf(&line[6], "%s", origin);
                    hexOrigin = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    sscanf(&line[5], "%s", origin);
                    hexOrigin = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        line[0] = 0;
    }

    int intOrigin = -1;
    if (origin > 0 && hexOrigin == 1)
    {
        if (strlen(origin) > 4)
        {
            printf("ERROR 2: Bad origin address. Address too big for 16 bits.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            intOrigin = fromHexToDecimal(origin);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sscanf(origin, "%d", &intOrigin);
    }
    return intOrigin;
}

void removeSpaces(char line[])
{
    char* currentLetter = line;
    for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
    {
        if (line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != '\t')
        {
            *currentLetter = line[i];
            currentLetter++;
        }
    }
    *currentLetter = 0;
}


void toUpperCase(char line[])
{
    for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
    {
        if (line[i] >= 97 && line[i] <= 122)
        {
            line[i] -= 32;
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a test file I'm running it on that looks something like this

```html
;Test file for assembly

;This is a comment

.orig x3000
 ADD R1, R2, R3
 add R0, R3, #10
 
 and R1, R1, R2
 AND R0, R3, #-10
L0   
 BR L1
 BRN L0
 BRZ L1
 BRP L0
 BRNZ L1
 BRNP L0
 BRZP L1
 BRNZP L0
 LD R1, L2
 LDR R1, R2, #-5
 L1   
 NOT R3, R4  
 ST R5, L2
 STR R6, R1, #-5 
 TRAP x20
 TRAP x21
 TRAP x22
 TRAP x23
 TRAP x24
 TRAP x25
 L2 .FILL  0 
L3 .FILL  0  
L4 .FILL  0 
 
.END

If I print out each line it looks like this

0@
;Test file for assembly

;This is a comment

.ORIGX3000
ADDR1,R2,R3
ADDR0,R3,#10

ANDR1,R1,R2
ANDR0,R3,#-10
L0   
BRL1
BRNL0
BRZL1
BRPL0
BRNZL1
BRNPL0
BRZPL1
BRNZPL0
LDR1,L2
LDRR1,R2,#-5
L1   
NOTR3, R4  
STR5,L2
STRR6,R1,#-5 
TRAPx20
TRAPx21
TRAPx22
TRAPx23
TRAPx24
TRAPx25
L2.FILL0 
L3.FILL0  
L4.FILL0 
 
.END
```

Comment: Your check of `fscanf`'s return value is wrong. You should check for `== 1`, not `!= EOF`. Also, there is a stray `s` in your format string.

Comment: to be entirely honest that part was provided completely by my professor. Do you mean the s inside "%[^\n]s"?

Comment: Your professor shouldn't be allowed to teach C.

Comment: Well lol uhm, isn't the s used for the fscanf to indicate that we are reading in a string like if we just used %s?

Comment: `"%[^\n]"`. The `%[...]` *character class* conversion specifier is complete unto itself. There is no need for the `'s'` at the end. Testing `!= EOF` does not catch a *matching* or *input* failure. To validate `fscanf` you must test that the expected number of conversions took place (1 in your case) *in addition to* testing `EOF`. These among others are why you should be reading an entire line with `fgets` and then passing the filled buffer to `sscanf`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to do that =\ I have to use fscanf here to complete this step. This part was given to me and I am only give the task of filling in the parts around it and his automated tests look for certain constructs otherwise it fails and I get a 0 =\

Comment: The trouble is that the `fscanf()` fails completely if the first line of the file contains just a newline.  The `%^[^\n]` finds a newline and leaves it in the input, and doesn't write anything to the string argument `line`, and returns `0` (because there wasn't EOF — there's still a newline in the buffer), but what's there doesn't match the format string.  So, the framework is broken if the input contains an all blank line.  The characters you see are a result of the uninitialized variable `line`.  The code is broken, and shouldn't be given to novice programmers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you lol, I have an intuition that it may have had something to do with that but wasn't 100% sure. But thank you all of you guys. That solved that problem, at least for this issue. I have a couple other issues I'm trying to sort out at this moment that I may end up having to make posts for just to try and get through it but I appreciate the help guys.

Comment: @DylanBeech that is the *input failure* case. Where the input ends before all conversion specifiers you designated encounter matching input. The *matching failure* case is where there is a mismatch between the conversion specifier used and the data, e.g. `"%d"` is used and `"dog"` is input. You must validate both by checking that the return equals the number of conversion specifiers used..